# crystal reports ver. 11 crashing when dual monitors?

Tags: crystal-reports, multiple-monitors

this is bit strange I noticed my crystal reports crash every time when I'm on dual monitor settings.

The program works fine when using on Primary monitor, but it keeps crashing when I move the app to extended display. Make a minor edit and crashes.

it was working fine on desktop and got upgraded to the laptop.

monitors are the same make and model.  -Windows 10 x64 bit

Answer (score 0):

fixed. I noticed moving the program to another screen seems to respond proeprly.

Answer (score 0):

My IT guy told me to do this and it has resolved the issue.  If using Windows 10:

1. Change the Lid Close Action.
   Control Panel > Power Options > Change Plan Settings > Change Advanced Power Settings > **On Battery** and **Plugged In** both should be set to: DO NOTHING

Close the lid on your laptop and only work off of the dual monitors.

2. Set your Power Settings to High.
   Control Panel > Power Options > Change Plan Settings > Change Advanced Power Settings > Intel Graphics Settings > **On Battery** and **Plugged In** both should be set to:  Maximum Performance.
3. Ensure Processor Power Management is set to 100%:
   Control Panel > Power Options > Change Plan Settings > Change Advanced Power Settings > Processor Power Management > Maximum Processor State > **On Battery** and **Plugged In** both should be set to:  100%.

By checking these 3 things and reconfiguring my laptop, this did the trick for me and I am now able to use the larger monitor for Crystal Reports.